# jQuery dataTables - passing json stringified data to server

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, datatables

I need to send custom data, in a JSON stringified format along with the regular data for every ajax call to the server.

Here is my javascript code,

```
   $('#dataList').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/ViewGenerator/GetPagedViewData",
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            var name = $('#viewName').val();
            var viewId = $('#viewId').val();
            var description = $('#viewDescription').val();
            var viewInfo = JSON.stringify(currentviewInfo);
            aoData.push({ "name": "viewId", "value": viewId });
            aoData.push({ "name": "viewName", "value": name });
            aoData.push({ "name": "viewDescription", "value": description });
            aoData.push({ "name": "viewInfo", "value": viewInfo });
        },
        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
            for (var i = 0; i < oObj.length; i++) {
                console.log(oObj[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

The controller's signature is :

```
public JsonResult GetPagedViews(int? iDisplayStart = 0, int? iDisplayLength = 0, int? sEcho = 0, string viewId = null, string viewName = null, string viewDescription = null, viewInfo viewInfo = null)
    {
```

When i view the js errors in chrome developer tool, i find a Bad Request (400) being made,
i am not able to find the exact location of the buggy code. Also, how can i set the application type to application/json for each of the datatables ajax calls.

Comment: This a bit late, but have you managed to sort out your issue?

Comment: @BrendanVogt: Thanks Brendan, I have fixed the issue using fnServerData Ajax Call. Anyways, you can post your solution here so that we can share our ways to deal with this problem. I will post mine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploration, I came across fnServerData Ajax Calling options. With the help of this API, i was able to complete this task. More details [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks)